# DELETE from another table with trigger/trigger function

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to use trigger to delete a row from a table when a column with the same value is delete from the original table

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testFunc()
  RETURNS trigger AS  
$func$
BEGIN  
   DELETE FROM emergencyinfo
   USING  massacts
   WHERE  emergencyinfo.actid = massacts.id;

RETURN NEW;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Trigger;

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger3 
AFTER DELETE ON massacts 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE testFunc();
```

This does not work, when i execute query 'delete from massacts where id=5', the row deletes from massacts but the row that holds actid=5 in emergencyinfo does not delete.

However, when i try this trigger by updating a row's id to 5 in massacts table, the row in emergencyinfo with actid=5 does delete.

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger3 
AFTER UPDATE ON massacts 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE testFunc();
```

I have tried to use BEFORE DELETE instead of AFTER, same issue persisted.

Comment: This: `... WHERE  emergencyinfo.actid = massacts.id;` is dangerous as that will `DELETE` everything in `emergencyinfo` that has an `actid` equal to `id` in `massacts`.  For  the `DELETE` trigger you would want `OLD.id` and for the `UPDATE` `NEW.id`. You can use `TG_OP` to distinguish between them. This is documented here [plpgsql trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Comment: Hey, from what i ve seen, the OLD comparison is made within the same table, how could i use OLD when i wanna compare tableA.id=tableB.old.id?  I tried to do WHERE  emergencyinfo.actid = OLD.id; that didnt give any errors but the same issue as before still persists.

Comment: 1) The trigger is on `massacts` table so `OLD.id` will be the `massacts.id` that was just deleted, where as `massacts.id` will be all `massacts.id`'s that match a corresponding `emergencyinfo.actid`. 2) Did you try `DELETE FROM emergencyinfo  WHERE  emergencyinfo.actid = OLD.id`? 3) Why not set up a `FOREIGN KEY` between `massacts` and `emergencyinfo` with a `ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Comment: Thanks for the help, yes i eventually got it to work just fine. I had to declare an int variable then use id_to_delete = OLD.id; As for the reason i had to use foreign key, its a school project/hw, they make me do it this way specifically.

Comment: Typo: I mean i had to not use foreign key.